# Want to make a persistent service like Whatsapp/Truecaller

Tags: android, service

**Description of Truecaller/Whatsapp service**

**Note: Here force close means killing the app by pressing and holding back button not just stopping the service from service manager/app manager (see [Kill app back button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1Knp.jpg)).

After killing the truecaller app when I make a call it restarts automatically, same for whatsapp also, After killing it when a message is received it still shows the notification and restarts the service. These services also restarts after a few delay

---

**What I have done so far to achieve this**

I want to make a service like this so called my backgroundservice from onDestroy() of my backgroundservice class. Code for this: ServiceDemo 0.1

```
public class BackgroundService extends Service {
@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Toast.makeText(BackgroundService.this, "Service Started...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {

    Intent intentService = new Intent(this,BackgroundService.class);
    startService(intentService);

    Toast.makeText(BackgroundService.this, "Service Will Be Restarted...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

The service is restarting if I stop it from my service manager. But if I force close/kill it , it's gone.

---

After this I implemented Broadcast receiver which doesn't make any difference. Code for this: ServiceDemo 0.2

**BackgroundService.java**

```
public class BackgroundService extends Service {
@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Toast.makeText(BackgroundService.this, "Service Started...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(BackgroundService.this, "Service Will Be Restarted...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    sendBroadcast(new Intent("RestartMe"));
}
}
```

**RestartBackgroundService.java**

```
public class RestartBackgroundService extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

//        I have also used AlarmManager , but it doesn't make any difference for me
//        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
//        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, new Intent(context, BackgroundService.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
//        int interval = 5000;
//        am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,     System.currentTimeMillis() + interval, interval, pi);

    context.startService(new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(),BackgroundService.class));
}
}
```

---

As whatsapp is using gcm so I thought if I implement that it would help.
Then I implemented firebase cloud messaging (fcm) to receive push notification and I removed the code to restart background service from onDestroy().

Now if I stops the service from service manager it remains stopped then I sends a notification from my firebase console it receives the notification as google's gcm service is running. If I click the notification it restarts my service again.

But if I force close/kill my app no notifications are received though gcm service is running. Code for this: (I posted a link to make the description a bit short)

[ServiceDemo 0.3](https://gist.github.com/Sp4Rx/5c517bad69812a69219a9018f60ef086)

---

**What I want**

I want my service to be persistent like whatsapp/truecaller even if I force close it. They keep on starting after a few delays. And I want to achieve it without using third parties like fcm.

If someone can give any hints/solution about how to start my service when a particular system service/app (like dialer) starts that would be a great help.

Comment: "force close means killing the app by pressing and holding back button" -- Android does not have this capability. Your device or custom ROM added it. You will need to discuss with the device manufacturer or custom ROM developer what this actually does.

Comment: Yes you are right @CommonsWare that this option is available in custom roms  or can be achieved in rooted devices but I don't have any issue with it. I wanted to know how these apps like truecaller/whatsapp works so that its services gets restarted even after I force close it and these are not system apps or require root permission. I wanted my service in a way that will survive force close.